# See other's Android location on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, geolocation, google, android

I have an Android phone (Nexus 6P) and my wife has an iPhone 6.

We would like to have the same functionality as `Find My Friends` offers, without both having iPhones.
Thus, we share each other's location through Google.

I have no problem seeing her location on my Android.

Previously, my wife could see my location using the iPhone `Google+` app. There used to be a `Locations` tab in the app, showing my location. Now, the `Location` tab is gone. [The Google support article "See friends' locations on a map"](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3302509?hl=en) is obsolete.

Is there any other way on an iPhone to see someone else's location information?

We both have location history, reporting and sharing in Google turned on. My wife has both the `Google+` and the `Google` app installed and running on the iPhone (and is logged in, of course).

Comment: Let me know if my answer solves your problem, and if there is anything else I can do to help!

Comment: Google+ probably isn't the best solution here, especially since it's being slowly phased out http://www.inc.com/john-brandon/the-long-painful-road-to-finally-end-the-google-misery.html

Answer (score 1):

My family—one Nexus 6P user and two iPhone 6 users—is really happy with Life360. It provides just the same service as Find My Friends (letting family members view each other's current location), just cross-platform. It isn't battery intensive, works great, and even has some additional features as compared to Find My Friends.

Life360 is free on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.life360.android.safetymapd&hl=en) and the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/family-locator-by-life360/id384830320?mt=8).

Comment: Interesting idea. Not a completely free app, though.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn Everything you can do with Find Friends is free with Life360; the paid tier just gets you added perks! We've been using the free tier for months and have loved it, it has not once let us down.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.bjuremo.hereiam.lite

It can share with email, text messages or through other apps